# Use a bibtex file with a different extension

Tags: bibtex, external-files

Is it possible to tell bibtex to use a file with a specific extension?

If you do `\bibliography{mybib.org}`, then bibtex simply looks for a file called `mybib.org.bib`. Is there any way to avoid the `.bib` extension?

*Using texlive 2011-1.*

Comment: TeX has no interest in the file *.bib -- The compiler `bibtex` uses the file to create your bibliography file with the extension `bbl`.

Comment: @MarcoDaniel My bad, I was just trying to expressi that I'm using the texlive distribution of Bibtex. I'll fix that.

Comment: Not with BibTeX; it *requires* the `.bib` extension.

Comment: If you're managing your bib files in Emacs org-mode, you can give the file a .bib ending and add a local variable to the file to tell Emacs to consider it to be an org file.

Comment: Offtopic: but if @Tyler is right (seems likely), I wonder what the advantage is of writing a 'bib' file using `org-mode`.  I use `org-mode` a fair bit, but I'm not sure what the advantage would be in this case..?  As for your extension problem, you might consider switching to using `biber` and `biblatex`.

Comment: @Tyler Yeah, I'll just have to do that. I just wanted to check if there wasn't a way to make bibtex behave first.

Comment: @jon, Bruce: I'm also curious. What do you get with org-mode that you prefer over bibtex-mode?

Comment: @jon I don't use org-mode to write the actual bib entries, just to organize them in general. Each paper has its own headline (with the same title as the paper). Most importantly, org-mode allows me to schedule when I want to read a paper (which then shows up on my agenda views), or just add "TODO" to those which I want to read eventually but don't know when. It also makes it extra convenient to write tons of itemized notes about each paper (plain text inside the headline).

Comment: @Tyler  I rarely need to edit the actual entries, which is why bibtex-mode isn't that useful for me. The actual bibtex entry goes on a sub-headline (called `** Bibtex`) inside each paper's headline. That way it is nicely hidden away from view, and I can focus on the title and notes I've made about the paper. Since the entry never starts with a  `*` it doesn't bother org-mode in any way. And since bibtex just completely ignores everything outside the bib-entries, they both play nice with each other.

Comment: That sounds interesting. I keep an enormous single .bib file, with my notes embedded in a comments field within the entry. It's easily searched using bibtex-mode, but is becoming unwieldy. Could you post an example of your bib.org layout somewhere? I'd be very interested in seeing it.

Comment: Hmm, interesting.  these days I use `org-mode` to take notes, but I use one file per article or book rather than keep it all in one file.  My `.bib` file has over 2500 entries and is already almost 900 Kb; my 'notes' files adds up to 16 Mb (hard to say, really, since some are quite old and were written in Word/Open|LibreOffice, etc.).  It is a very interesting idea, however; I may try to adapt elements of the idea.  Anyway, the 'Local Variables:' approach is very simple if you only have one `.bib` file that you want to present to `emacs` as an `org` file!

Comment: Sure, I'll put it on github or something tomorrow.

Comment: @Tyler and Jon Here's the example. https://github.com/Bruce-Connor/org-bibtex Hope it helps.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The compilation by `bibtex` doesn't allow such a combintion. The help function of the compiler demonstrates it:

```
localhost:~ marco$ bibtex --help
Usage: bibtex [OPTION]... AUXFILE[.aux]
  Write bibliography for entries in AUXFILE to AUXFILE.bbl,
  along with a log file AUXFILE.blg.
-min-crossrefs=NUMBER  include item after NUMBER cross-refs; default 2
-terse                 do not print progress reports
-help                  display this help and exit
-version               output version information and exit
```